# Convert(re-write) array_filter code into foreach loop

Tags: magento2, php

I have an array $arrItems['items'] in which 5 more arrays (associate array) and each array contain 5 element (with the keys: f_name, l_name, contact, address, seller_id).

I want to get all those arrays (from $arrItems['items']) in which element of seller_id is 1 like "seller_id"=>"1,2,3" OR "seller_id"=>"3,2,1" OR "seller_id"=>"4,6,2" OR "seller_id"=>"5,3,4" OR "seller_id"=>"2,1,2" Array given below

`$currentUser=1;
        $arr= array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($e) use ($currentUser) {
            return in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $e["current_seller_id"]));
        });`

actually am apply filter on Order Items Collection.
Then it filter perfectly but not set array in order grid. Order Grid is buffering not display data.
When i write same code in foreach loop then data in order items grid set perfectly But my foreach loop not filter right. it return some extra array where seller_id not exist. My Foreach loop code is there :

```
$seller_order_arr = [];
    foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
        if (strpos($row['current_seller_id'] ,",") > 1 && $row['current_seller_id'] != null){
            $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
        }
        if($row['current_seller_id'] == $currentUser){
            $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;
```

anyone help me to re-write **array_filter** code in **foreach** code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this should be the equivalent to your array_filter approach:

```
$currentUser=1;
$seller_order_arr = [];

foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
    if ($row['current_seller_id'] != null){
        if (in_array($currentUser, explode(",", $row['current_seller_id']))){
            $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
$arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;
```